# pass array between two php files

Tags: php, redirect, header, parameters

I have a php file that needs to redirect to another, but I need to pass an array to the second file.  How can I do this.

I know this is wrong, but I need something logically similar to this.

```
<?php 
       $arr = array('this'=>'is', 'some'=>'stuff');
       header("someurl.php", vals=>$arr);
 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "pass between files"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to expose your $array, you MUST use PHP inbuild session support.

```
session_start(); // DO CALL ON TOP OF BOTH PAGES
$_SESSION['array'] = $array;
echo $_SESSION['array']; // GIVES SAME $array FOR BOTH PAGES
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query):

```
header("Location: someurl.php?" . http_build_query($arr));
```

Answer (score 6):

That's not how you do headers. it'd have to be

```
header("Location: someurl.php?vals=$arr");
```

however, this would just generat the URL

```
someurl.php?vals=Array
```

Note that a redirect by its nature cannot do a POST. it will result in a new GET request, meaning you have to pass data in the URL. If you have a very large url, you're almost guaranteed to lose most of it, as URLs have length limits.

However, if it's a short one, you can try something like:

```
$url = 'someurl.php?vals=' . url_encode(serialize($arr));
header("Location: $url");
```

and hope it works.

Comment: PRECISELY!! this is the best answer! a common misconception most devs have.

Comment: Wouldn't `base64_encode` be a better option here? I think `urlencode` has worse length ratio properties than base64. (base64 is 33% I believe - I can easily see `urlencode` going over that). Also, if you have simple data the serialize is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 3):

You may store the array on the session or the request and then retrieve it.

If it is a different request you'll have to do it in the session.

```
$_SESSION['myarray'] = $array_you_want_to_store;
```

And then.

```
$array_you_want_to_retrieve = $_SESSION['myaarray'];
```

Comment: This gives considerable issues if the user uses tabbed browsing (=everyone) and clicks multiple links at once.